# php regex for string between :" and "

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to grab the string between `:"` and `"` in an array in PHP using preg_match_all.

eg:

```
"I am a string"("string"):"Need this string", "I am a string"("string"):"Need this string", etc, etc
```

I had the following but it returns no results or errors and works in the regex builders I've tried.

```
/\"\:"(.*?)\"/ and #/\"\:"(.*?)\"/#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression can be made much simpler like this:

```
if (preg_match_all('/:"(.*?)"/', $str, $matches)) {
    // $matches[1] will contain all the strings you want
}
```

Comment: isn't correct.. expression matches strings like `':"string","adfadf"'` instead of `':"string"'`

Comment: @vlcekmi3 I'm using a non-greedy pattern by adding a question mark. Alternatively I could have used the U modifier.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern:

```
#:"([^"]*)"#
```